# What is the domain of the function $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\operatorname{arctan}(t)}{t}dt$?

Tags: integration

What is the domain of the following function?
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\operatorname{arctan}(t)}{t}dt$$

On the one hand, the internal function is not defined at 0, but on the other hand, it's defined on every other point except zero, so the region can be calculated.

Comment: After "filling in" the hole at $t=0$ the integrand $\arctan(t)/t$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ so the integral is defined for all real $x$.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: As an aside, $F(1)$ is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).

Answer (score 1):

$F$ has a well defined integral from $(-\infty, \infty)$. The integral at $0$ is well defined, you can see that by expanding the taylor series of $$\arctan(t)/t = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{2n+1},$$ which converges for $|t| < 1$. For regions away from zero, the function is a ratio of continuous function with the denominator nonvanishing. Thus the integral is well defined for all $x$.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. So does it mean that, by definition, a function that expands to a taylor series is defined on the domain where the series converges, even if the function itself is clearly undefined (e.g. has a division by zero)?. (Sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language and using math language in English is unusual for me.)

Comment: The point here is that we can see that the zero of $\arctan(t)$ and the zero of $t$ cancel each other. Just like $\frac{t-t^3}{t} = 1-t^2$. The result is that you have a function that is continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function can be extended in $x=0$ to obtain a continuous function defined on the whole real line. Hence such extended function is Riemann integrable and hence its integral on $[0,x]$ is well defined for all $x$. Now remember that if you modify a function in a finite number of points, its integral does not change. Hence you can extended your function with *any value* in $x=0$ and obtain an Riemann integrable function.

However, strictly speaking, Riemann integrals on the interval $[a,b]$ is defined only for functions which are defined on the whole interval $[a,b]$. If the function is only defined on the interval $(a,b]$ this should be considered an *improper integral* i.e.:
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\, dt = \begin{cases}\lim_{a\to 0^+}  \int_a^x f(t)\, dt & \text{if } x>0 \\ \lim_{a\to 0^-}\int_a^x f(t)\, dt & \text {if $x<0$ }\\ 0 &\text{if } x=0\end{cases}.
$$
But, again, since the function $f$ can be extended with continuity in $x=0$ the limit exists and is equal to the integral on $[0,x]$ of the extended function.

Comment: So formally, without extending the function, F(x) is not defined at x=0? Also, the fixup of a→0+ applies only for x>0, but it can also be negative.

Comment: But wait, if f(x) is not defined at x=0, is F(x) defined at all? F(x) integrates from 0 to x, so it's kind of forced to "touch" zero.

Comment: It much depends on the definitions you are given. Notice however that if you decide it is not defined for $x=0$ it is not defined for *any*
 value of $x$. Hence you have two possibilities: either the function is defined for all $x$ or for no $x$.

Comment: @Paul, for $x < 0$ the interpretation as an improper integral would be $\lim_{a\to0^-} \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: @Paul: thanks i've corrected my answer. In fact it is indeed not clear how the improper integral could be possibly defined on the empty interval $(a,a)$... I think that it should be $0$ by definition.